# How can I handle loop running twice in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project in which I am using dragster library.I am trying to build a cards game . I stuck when I am trying to get values of card using dragster function.It runs loop twice  which I dont want(first it runs 13 times then it run to what I want) .I want only that loop that runs last as it contain all elements which I need.First one run 13 times always.Its running like this:

```
0
1
.
.
upto 12
then it again run
0 to 11(this loop I want).
```

How can I ignore above loop.
My code:

```
$('.test .block').find('div.Hearts').each(function(i,val){
                 let h = $(val).find('p#number').text();
                  console.log(h)

            })
```

Comment: You need to find out why it runs twice, rather than add more code to stop it doing that.

Comment: you say the second loop has what you want ... so what does the first loop (0 - 12) "have"? and this code snippet suggests you have multiple `<p>` elements with the same `id` - which is invalid HTML for a start - also, there are 13 hearts in a deck of cards, just sayin'

Comment: I am using dragster package and using dragster function also which also on drag it runs loops and after dropping element it also run (this one which I want)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with understanding jQuery's

Each
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Find
https://api.jquery.com/find/

The issue most likely relates to you having multiple elements returned in the find which the each then runs on.

I would advise you either use more specific selectors - for debugging log out $(this) from inside the each to see which element it's targeting.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, there must be multiple elements returned by find() method.